# Application crashes while logging out in iPAD

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management, ios4

My question is specific to iPAD, and I also aware of the basic memory management of iOS, but I am having a different problem.

As I have build an application where I have several UIViewControllers and UIViews,
I have a loginController thats gets called when I launch the App.

My MainView is a single screen with all the ViewController loaded and placed at their respective places and the app runs fine and smoothly.

Problem:

Problem comes when I logout, most of the time my App crashes by saying `EXC_BAD` on the 
`[super dealloc]` line of my mainView controller.

As for now on I have added a custom function `cleanUP` in all my viewControllers that gets called when user logout from the app.

Is this the right approach ?

As I know that we can clean up in our `didload` etc. function and the dealloc gets called too.

but here i have an iPAD when my all viewControllers are just open in front of me, They will be closed or not visible when I logout from the App.

So how to approach on my crash issue and How to manage memory here in my iPAD?

Comment: I'm only guessing but some people may be scared off by double question marks.

Comment: @DanAbramov :P so I will help then to remove their fear..here's the edited one

Comment: Probably because you didn't post any relevant code...so this question can only be speculated on.  How can anyone know what you are doing in your "custom function"?  Logging out is also not a standard action in iOS, so we have no idea what you are doing there either.

Comment: @borrrden As my custom Function name says "cleanUp" I am just removing any subviews in it.

Comment: Post some code please, the `cleanUp` method and the body of the `dealloc`

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know to resolve bad-access problems is to use Instruments with the Zombie tool. As you probably know, when you get a bad access issue, is because you try to access to an object that is deallocated.

Try go to Product -> Profile and choose Zombie. Hit record and reproduce your crash. then inspect the pointer to the object that produced that crash and look for the retain count.